# pip install pywin32 fails on mac machine

Tags: python, macos, doc

How can i download pip install pywin32 on mac machine. my requirement to convert pdf to docs file using below code

```
import glob
import win32com.client
import os

word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.visible = 0

pdfs_path = "C:\\Users\\bthakur4\\Downloads\\pdf\\"
for i, doc in enumerate(glob.iglob(pdfs_path +"inputfiles\\" +"*[A-Za-z0-9 _].pdf")):
    #print(doc)
    filename = doc.split('\\')[-1]
    in_file = os.path.abspath(doc)
    print("\n")
    print("converting file: ",in_file)
    wb = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
    out_file = os.path.abspath(pdfs_path + "outputfiles\\" +filename[0:-4]+ ".docx".format(i))
    wb.SaveAs2(out_file, FileFormat=16)
    print("success...")
    print("output file: ",out_file)
    wb.Close()

word.Quit()
```

. or any other way to do so ???

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't. pywin32 is a **Windows** Python wrapper for windows API calls

Comment: right, thanks , any help please for permission denied error on installing <pip install PyPDF2>

Comment: Try to use "sudo" ?